# The difference between declaring a variable as "var $foo" or "$foo" in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

The title explains it all. What's the difference?

```
var $foo;
$bar;
```

What's the main difference between this two variables?

I've noticed that "var $foo" is mostly used to declare class attributes, but why is it so?

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In PHP 4 `var` is used to define variables in classes. In PHP 5 it is deprecated, and you must use `public`, `private`, or `protected` instead. Outside of classes it shouldn't have any effect (although you might get a warning in PHP 5).

Comment: you get a warning in which of both cases?